# Spring Cloud Gateway Mvc throwing IO exception frequently and Routing failing with 403 Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I am migrating zuul configuration into spring cloud gateway mvc. I configured following in spring boot application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      mvc:
        routes:
          - id: rabbitmq
            uri: http://localhost:15672/
            predicates:
              - Path=/rabbitmq/**
              - Method=GET, POST
            filters:
              - StripPrefix=1
```

How ever its successfully redirected in local machine but frequently failing in server with following error

```
java.io.IOException: closed
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseSubscribers$HttpResponseInputStream.current(ResponseSubscribers.java:460) ~[java.net.http:na]
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseSubscribers$HttpResponseInputStream.read(ResponseSubscribers.java:499) ~[java.net.http:na]
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.transferTo(InputStream.java:782) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:150) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.RestClientProxyExchange.lambda$doExchange$3(RestClientProxyExchange.java:52) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.GatewayServerResponseBuilder$WriteFunctionResponse.writeToInternal(GatewayServerResponseBuilder.java:218) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.AbstractGatewayServerResponse.writeTo(AbstractGatewayServerResponse.java:103) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.HandlerFunctionAdapter.handle(HandlerFunctionAdapter.java:111) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
```

spring boot version= '3.2.3'
spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc version: 4.1.0

I have tried changing spring boot security config and connection time out properties with http client but nothing is working..

This IO exception with RestClientProxyChange should not occur in server.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was hopeless here I changed my approach to route the service using nginx ingress controlller instead of spring cloud gateway. I completely removed my spring cloud gateway MVC code in my spring boot service and achieved the routing using Kubernets nginx ingress controller.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).